# Requested remote registry access is not allowed

Tags: c#, permissions, registry, remote-registry

Requested registry access is not allowed
I want to access Remote Pc's Registry but it cant allow me to do so.

Below is my code

```
private static void CheckRemoteRegistry()
 {

try {

    string serverName = "DESKTOP-2ME3g20M";

    NetworkShare share = new
    NetworkShare(serverName, "C$", "ARIgTEAM", "02123541");

    share.Connect();

    String ProductName = string.Empty;
    String InstanceName = string.Empty;
    RegistryKey key;
    RegistryKey key2;

    RegistryKey Remotekey = 
            RegistryKey.OpenRemoteBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, serverName, RegistryView.Registry64);

    if (Remotekey != null) 
                   {
        key = Remotekey.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion");

        key2 = Remotekey.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\Instance Names\SQL");

        if (key != null) 
                  {
            ProductName = key.GetValue("ProductName").ToString();
            InstanceName = key.GetValue("MSSQLSERVER").ToString();
        }
    }
    share.Disconnect();
}
catch(Exception ex) {
    throw new Exception(ex.Message);
}
}
```

key = Remotekey.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion");
This Is Working

but

key2 = Remotekey.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\Instance Names\SQL");

this code show's me this error.

Comment: were you able to figure this out? I'm having this exact issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone is wondering.

Was able to solve the issue by granting permissions to the following area:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurePipeServers\winreg
```